# Add UTF-8 encoding to ResponseEntity

Tags: spring

I have a `responseEntity` like this one:

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("text/plain;charset=UTF-8"));

HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(jsonQuery, requestHeaders);
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

//Not in UTF-8!!
logger.debug("result: " + responseEntity.getBody());
```

But it's not encoded in `UTF-8` and produces characters like this: `Soci굩` . Is it possible to make it in `UTF-8` or add the encoding somehow in [restTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to add a `StringHttpMessageConverter` with `utf-8` in `restTemplate` bean like:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
            .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: down vote because of changing the question and eliminating the original question. you could ask the second question as an *UPDATE* or a new question

Comment: Also you can use: StandardCharsets.UTF_8 instead or Charset.forName("UTF-8")

Answer (score 6):

```
responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Request headers, not response headers? Shouldn't request headers be unmodifiable? I mean, they're sent by the client and shouldn't be allowed to be changed!

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the same problem just adding **charset=utf8** to my RequestMapping.

**Before**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/hal+json")
```

**After**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/hal+json;charset=utf8")
```

I add this to my other methods too. I hope this helps.

Comment: I believe that this should be the accepted answer. Even better if you replace RequestMapping by GetMapping

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. I need to POST a string object in request body with UTF-8.

text/plain

httpHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("text", "plain", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

applicaton/json

httpHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("applicaton", "json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> resposeEntity = null;

HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("text", "plain", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(stringContent, httpHeaders);
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);

if (HttpStatus.OK.equals(responseEntity.getStatusCode())) {
    logger.debug("... success ... result: " + responseEntity.getBody());
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach:

We know that By Default, `RestTemplate` StringHttpMessageConverter will be ISO-8859-1, So we can convert the response to UTF-8 like this.

```
 String responseDecodedToUTF8 = new String(responseEntity.getBody().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```